# Can't access object property even though should be there

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component in react that fetches a story that a user wrote from the backend. I then store the json in the `storyState` and when I log it, the needed properties like "title" are in there, but when I try to access the property title, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
```

Here is the code:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const StoryPage = () => {
    const [storyState, setStoryState] = useState({
        story: {},
        isLoaded: false,
        error: null,
    });

    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const id = urlParams.get('storyid');

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000//getstory?storyid=' + id)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('response is', response);
                if (response.status !== '200') {
                    let err = Error;
                    err.message = 'Invalid response code: ' + response.status;
                    setStoryState({ error: err });
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((json) => {
                console.log('json is', json);
                setStoryState({
                    story: json.story,
                    isLoaded: true,
                });
            });
    }, []);

    console.log('storystate.story', storyState.story);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>{storyState.story.title}</h1>
        </>
    );
};

export default StoryPage;
```

I checked StackOverflow and tried using `JSON.parse`, which didn't work unfortunately.

When I do `< h1 >{storyState.story}</ h1 >` I get the whole object in string form with all the properties as expected.

Here is my console:

[image]

Comment: At the first render it's not yet available , so you put a loader or render null and then after available show the data you are trying to .... Just like `if(!data)return null;return(whaterver u want next );` To understand this try logging the storyState.story inside return ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is at this line -

```
if (response.status !== "200") {
}
```

It should be 200 instead of "200". You can check the `console.log("response is", response);`, it's numeric 200 not string.

Note: Always use the below construct to setState for objects -

```
{ ...previousState, { newkey: newvalue } }
```

The above uses the previous values of object and replaces with new values.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me! From now on I'll use this construct to set state!

Answer (score 1):

In the very first render, data is not available, hence you have to render
`<h1>{storyState.story.title}</h1>` only when the data is fetched and available so add an if statement in the render or you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) too

```
  <h1>{storyState?.story?.title}</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you too Tarun, your answer actually worked as well!

Answer (score 0):

There could be a delay in fetching data from server, you can add a loader in it which checks if there is a value in  `storySTate` then render the data or add another useEffect function which logs file whenever there is a change in storyState hook eg:

```
 useEffect(() => {   
        console.log(storyState.story)
    }, [storyState])
```